# Python format strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How can i print data in such a way, using f-strings in Python? Note that the part of speech should be exactly in the middle above the corresponding word, and there should be exactly one space between the words themselves.

[image]

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you tried? We're not here to write code for you. And what does the data look like? Is it lists of strings or one big string? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh this is ugly.

```py
words = "I omitted the raspberries and added strawberries instead".split()
parts = "PRP VBD DT NNS CC VBD NNS RB".split()

print(*[f"{part:^{max(len(word), len(part))}s}" for word, part in zip(words, parts)])
print(*[f"{word:^{max(len(word), len(part))}s}" for word, part in zip(words, parts)])
```

```
PRP   VBD   DT      NNS     CC   VBD      NNS        RB   
 I  omitted the raspberries and added strawberries instead
```

Precomputing the window size makes it a bit less ugly

```
words = "I omitted the raspberries and added strawberries instead".split()
parts = "PRP VBD DT NNS CC VBD NNS RB".split()
windows = [max(len(word), len(part)) for word, part in zip(words, parts)]

print(*[f"{part:^{window}s}" for part, window in zip(parts, windows)])
print(*[f"{word:^{window}s}" for word, window in zip(words, windows)])
```

```
PRP   VBD   DT      NNS     CC   VBD      NNS        RB   
 I  omitted the raspberries and added strawberries instead
```

Comment: Simpler: `for k in parts, words: print(*[... zip(k, windows)])`

Comment: @wjandrea: Oo that's nice.